# Scikit-learn Scaling Question (inverse_transform)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Hoping someone on here can help, I'm struggling to get prediction values back to "unscaled" values. I'm using StandardScaler() in sklearn.preprocessing . My dataset is a numpy array with 4 columns (called dataset).

**I've tried:**

```
# full dataset scaled, then split to 
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X,Y, test_size = 0.4) 

# model looks good but can't inverse_transform(Y_pred) obviously. 
Y_pred = adam.predict(X_test)

scaled X_train, X_test # individually 
# model comes out bad

scaled X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test # individually 
# model comes out bad
```

Am I applying scaling in an incorrect way?

Any suggestions on how to inverse scale of Y_pred on scaled model run?

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: always make sure that you include your code properly when submitting questions on **SE**.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Perhaps you can include example input data and how you want the output to look. This will help people to understand and answer your problem.

Comment: You are first scaling and then splitting the data which should not be done. You should first split, then scale the training data and then use that original scaling to transform test data. Anyways show how you scaled on each of the cases you shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Here was my workaround:

```
#standard scaler used to condition data
def scaler(x):
    mu = statistics.mean(x)
    stddev = statistics.stdev(x)
    standardized = (x-mu)/stddev
    return(standardized)

#Split data into X, Y and condition (X are the "features", Y is the forecasted/predicted price or "target")
Y = dataset[:,6]
ymu = statistics.mean(Y) #before scaler transform, get mean to inverse scaler transform after model
ystddev = statistics.stdev(Y) #before scaler transform, get stdev
Y = scaler(Y) #scale (i.e. condition/transform) forecasted price data
Xprice = dataset[:,4]
Xvolume = dataset[:,5]
Xprice = scaler(Xprice) #scale (i.e. condition/transform) price data
Xvolume = scaler(Xvolume) #scale (i.e. condition/transform) volume data
X = np.vstack((Xprice, Xvolume)).T #create 2D array of scale features
```

Then after test/train split and running the model:

```
Y_pred = adam.predict(X_test)
#undo scaling after model is run to get back to original scale
Y_test_inverse = (Y_test * ystddev) + ymu
Y_pred_inverse = (Y_pred * ystddev) + ymu
```

This produced good results with the actual scale of Y data and Y predict being correct (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I have used to scale data for use in an LSTM model. The data set is Open, High, Low, Close financial data. The model uses past values of Open, High, Low, and Close to try and predict what the Close will be at some point in the future thus scaling of all data is needed but the output Close needs to be inverse scaled back into an actual price point.

Start by instantiating two scaler objects depending on what scaler you are using:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
scaler_single = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
```

Use `scaler` to transform the Open, High, and Low data and `scaler_single`to scale the Close data. Then build the scaled data set by concatenating the results. `ohlcv` is a Pandas DataFrame object.

```
scaled_data = np.concatenate([scaler.fit_transform(ohlcv[['Open', 'High', 'Low']]), 
                                  scaler_single.fit_transform(ohlcv[['Close']])], axis = 1)
```

Now in order to inverse scale the outputted Close data, use the `inverse_transform` method of the `scaler_single` object. `predicted_prices` is the array returned by my model.

```
real_prices = scaler_single.inverse_transform(predicted_prices)
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I’m actually doing something very similar, I converted my dataframe to an array with timestamp, price, volume, and predictedprice(i.e. shifted data). A few questions, are your “predicted prices” part of your dataset?  Do you perform a transform on the on your prediction set before and after the model?  I’m thinking if the X (price) data is scaled before the model “learns” then the Y data would have to be scaled before/after too?  Is there another advantage to using StandardScaler (instead of making my own scaler) besides extra lines of code?
Thank you again!